# Crafting WP_Query array, sort by date

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, sort, front-end, formatting

question about wordpress WP_Query:

**'post_type' => 'event_date'** outputs dd/mm/yy ex: 31122012

I would like to order my frontend **'event_date'** output not by latest WP post entry
but by latest **'event_date'**

Already tried **'order' => 'ASC'** that sort only on WP post entry

Heres my code:

```
$arg = array('post_type' => 'livedates');
$the_query = new WP_Query($arg);
while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
$date = str_split(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true), 2);

//the loop

endwhile;
```

Comment: Do you mean event date in a custom field? You'll need to store the date in reverse first of all. There are many questions on this site regarding sorting by meta data, I suggest doing a search.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort a query by a specified post meta field as a number or as a text field.
Example:

```
$query_args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'event_date',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
 );
 $event_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```